# Where should I create my thread? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, ios

What is the best place to start a new thread? Should I create it in the Application Delegate, or can I start it from any other class for example a singleton?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is entirely dependent on why you need a new thread. For such a broad question, the answer is the App Delegate, but for a more specific question the answer may be different.

Comment: got it, the background thread will handle sync with server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're joining the thread, then you will typically want to create the thread local (or accessible to) the creation site, or in the same object's implementation. you'll usually join or use a task based interface when you want execution of the *current* thread to block until the threads/tasks complete.

if detaching (likely if you `alloc` an `NSThread` or use a `detach...` call), then it may be created wherever it makes the most sense in your program's flow.

That means you should favor 'local' as opposed to centralized in both cases.

If you use a task based interface (e.g. `NSOperation`), then you may need to centralize some things so many clients may reach an operation queue (as an example).

extracting detail from the comments: if you create a detached thread to interact with a server, then it is likely a good idea to create the thread in your implementation which interacts with the server, or the client code that interacts with those implementations. The app delegate is not a good choice when the cause/effect does not need to be centralized.